# Short if else javascript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm trying to understand how does this piece of code work. I know that the ternary operator is `condition ? option1 : option2` but I don't know how does this work in this scenario.

```
constructor(minSupport: number, minConfidence: number, debugMode: boolean) {
            this.minSupport = minSupport ? minSupport === 0 ? 0 : minSupport : 0.15;
            this.minConfidence = minConfidence ? minConfidence === 0 ? 0 : minConfidence : 0.6;
            this.debugMode = debugMode || false;
        }
```

Comment: Who wrote this?? Double checking for falsy doesnt make sense.

Comment: It's nested ternary, it would have really benefited from some parentheses (at the very least)

Comment: @Jonasw, the double check makes sense for checking that an explicit `0` was passed, but the code should be written in a way to make it more clear.

Comment: `minSupport === 0 ? 0 : minSupport` makes no sense (except when caring for `-0`, but that should be noted in a comment)

Comment: @zzzzBov 0 is falsy, therefore it will exit at the first ternary and wont go into the nested one which checks for 0 ?

Comment: Oh right, yea, just goes to show how badly formatted it was because I misread it, although the intent should be clear here.

Comment: Could just use `this.minSupport = minSupport || 0.15`

Comment: @DarrenYoung could, but shouldn't. I've seen (and made) this sort of mistake numerous times. In my view, the intent to preserve an explicit `0` while overriding implicit defaults (e.x. `undefined`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
this.minSupport = minSupport ? minSupport === 0 ? 0 : minSupport : 0.15;
```

translates into:

```
if (minSupport) {
  if (minSupport === 0) {
    this.minSupport = 0;
  } else {
    this.minSupport = minSupport;
  }
} else {
  this.minSupport = 0.15;
}
```

Given this example the others should be easy to work out. Personally I don't like nested ternary expressions like you've posted. A nice `if/then` statement is much simpler to work out the flow of logic.

Comment: That's some tremendous logic :)

Comment: The ternary expression actually is much simpler to work out because there's only one assignment to `this.minSupport` - you can easily see that the conditional flow affects only the value, not what happens with it.

Comment: I said "personally" :)

Comment: Oh thanks man, I didn't think this was permitted that's why I've started thinking it meant something different. Now I understand.

Answer (score 5):

This is a case study on why writing code as tersely as possible does not make it *better*.

Shoving everything into a single line makes it hard to read and comprehend the flow. I find that adding a little bit of formatting makes things much more legible:

```
this.minSupport =
  minSupport
    ? minSupport === 0
      ? 0
      : minSupport
    : 0.15;
```

There are a variety of ways to format that code to make it easier to digest. At this point we can walk through the logic:

*if `minSupport` is truthy:*

check if `minSupport` is zero (literally can't happen because `0` is not truthy). If it is (it can't be) set `this.minSupport` to `0`. Otherwise, set `this.minSupport` to whatever value `minSupport` contained.

*else if `minSupport` is falsey:*

set `this.minSupport` to `0.15`

So with that logic digested, it's clear that there's a secondary check that *intends* to preserve the value of `0`. The code is buggy, and the fix is to change the logic:

```
this.minSupport =
  minSupport
    ? minSupport
    : minSupport === 0
      ? minSupport
      : 0.15;
```

now with that reflow, we can look over the logic and see that it can be condensed. We want to set `this.minSupport` to `minSupport` if `minSupport` is truthy *or* if `minSupport` is `0`.

The simplification looks like:

```
this.minSupport =
  minSupport || minSupport === 0
    ? minSupport
    : 0.15;
```

Comment: Possibly even closer to the intended meaning: `this.minSupport = isNaN(minSupport) ? 0.15 : Number(minSupport)` or `this.minSupport = (typeof minSupport == "number" && !isNaN(minSupport)) ? minSupport : 0.15` - omit parts when knowing the type of the argument (as the parameter type annotation in the OP suggests)

Answer (score 3):

```
this.minSupport = minSupport ? minSupport === 0 ? 0 : minSupport : 0.15;
```

What it actually does (leaving away the non working stuff):

```
this.minSupport = minSupport || 0.15;
```

So basically, if minSupport is 0 or not passed (aka undefined), itll be 0.15 instead.

Comment: Well, that code does _work_, it's just much more verbose than is required.

Comment: @andy in my opinion: *work === does what it is supposed to*

Comment: @andy *So with that logic digested, it's clear that there's a secondary check that intends to preserve the value of 0. The code is buggy, and the fix is to change the logic*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete translation of the given snippet

```
constructor(minSupport: number, minConfidence: number, debugMode: boolean) {
  this.minSupport = (() => {
    if (minSupport) { 
      if (minSupport === 0) {
        // Interpreter will never reach this point because if minSupport is 0, it would straight away go to return 0.15 statement.
        return 0; 
      } else {
        return minSupport;
      }
    } else {
      return 0.15;
    }
  })();

  this.minConfidence = (() => {
    if (minConfidence) { 
      if (minConfidence === 0) {
        // Interpreter will never reach this point because if minConfidence is 0, it would straight away go to return 0.6 statement.
        return 0;
      } else {
        return minConfidence;
      }
    } else {
      return 0.6;
    }
  })();

  this.debugMode = (() => {
    if (debugMode) {
      return debugMode;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })();
}
```

The code snippet you shared, seems to be overdoing check for 0 which is already taken care of in the earlier if. You may probably want to rewrite your code to this.

```
constructor(minSupport: number, minConfidence: number, debugMode: boolean) {
  if (minSupport === 0 || minSupport) {
    this.minSupport = minSupport;
  } else {
    this.minSupport 0.15;
  }

  if (minConfidence === 0 || minConfidence) {
    this.minConfidence = minConfidence;
  } else {
    this.minConfidence = 0.15;
  }

  if (debugMode) {
    this.debugMode = debugMode;
  } else {
    this.debugMode = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The brackets will be more understandable

```
this.minSupport =    minSupport ?    (minSupport    === 0 ? 0 : minSupport)    : 0.15;
this.minConfidence = minConfidence ? (minConfidence === 0 ? 0 : minConfidence) : 0.6;
```

Comment: Did you just put in spaces?

Comment: and parenthesis, it's much more legible this way although it absolutely should include an explanation